# Java Swing center JLabel in JPanel with two JLabels

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, chess

I'm doing this chess using Swing.

[image]

For the board (JPanel) I'm using `new GridLayout(8, 8)` then I add 64 Squares (JPanel) to it.

Inside each Square I have a JLabel for the algebraic notation (A8, A7...), this label is well positionated.

The problem comes with the other JLabel containing the piece image, this one is not centered vertically, how can I center this JLabel in the Square?.

Here's the code for the Square:

```java
package org.victorpiles.escacs.client.gui;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * @author Víctor Piles
 */
public class Square extends JPanel {
    private static final String PIECE_ICON_PATH = "client/src/main/resources/pieces/";

    private static final Color LIGHT_COLOR = new Color(118, 150, 86, 255);
    private static final Color DARK_COLOR = new Color(238, 238, 210, 255);

    private final int position;

    public Square(int position) {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        setAlgebraicNotationLabel(position);

        this.position = position;
        setBackground(getSquareColor(position));
    }

    private void setAlgebraicNotationLabel(int position) {
        JLabel squarePosition = new JLabel(getAlgebraicNotation(position));
        squarePosition.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        add(squarePosition, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    /**
     * Calcula el color adequat per a la casella, basant-se en la seua posició.
     *
     * @param position La posició de la casella.
     *
     * @return El color de la casella: {@link #LIGHT_COLOR clar} o {@link #DARK_COLOR fosc}.
     */
    private Color getSquareColor(int position) {
        int row = position / 8;
        int column = position % 8;

        return (row + column) % 2 != 0 ? LIGHT_COLOR : DARK_COLOR;
    }

    /**
     * Calcula la notació algebraica per a la casella, basant-se en la seua posició.
     *
     * @param position La posició de la casella.
     *
     * @return La notació algebraica per a la casella.
     */
    private String getAlgebraicNotation(int position) {
        int row = 8 - (position / 8);
        char column = (char) ('a' + (position % 8));

        return ("" + column + row).toUpperCase();
    }

    public void updatePiece(char piece) {
        removeAll();

        BufferedImage pieceImage;

        if (piece == '-') {
            return;
        }

        String fileName = PIECE_ICON_PATH + piece + ".png";
        try {
            pieceImage = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
            System.out.println(position + " -> " + pieceImage.getHeight());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: 20/3/23 Manejar excepció
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        /* Actualitza la casella */
        setAlgebraicNotationLabel(position);
        add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(pieceImage)));
        validate();
    }
}
```

Comment: If screen space is sufficient, just put a dummy JLabel at the top with just a space character. If the image jlabel just takes the remaining space it should look centered vertically again. Otherwise you could still try some LayoutManager magic. I would even prefer custom drawing for a chess board like yours.

Comment: No need to play with dummy components, the BorderLayout will  center the label both vertically and horizontally in the space available to the CENTER of the panel, not the entire vertical space of the panel. The question is how do you know the graphics is centered within the image? Did you try just displaying the image on a JLabel to see if there is extra space at the bottom of the image? You can add a LineBorder to the label to see if the image itself is centered.

Comment: @camickr I think the image is not vertically centered because of the other JLabel taking part of the space, the JLabel with the algebraic notation is `BorderLayout.PAGE_END` aligned. What do you mean with this: `The question is how do you know the graphics is centered within the image?`, the image is 60x60 px, so its squared

Comment: Just because the image itself is 60x60 doesn't mean the the graphics drawing is centered. For example, the drawing of each piece could start at pixel 10 and leave 20 pixels of extra spaces at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way:

I add the notation label at the PAGE_END of the image label, for this purpose the image label layout is `setLayout(new BorderLayout());`

```java
private JLabel getAlgebraicNotationLabel(int position) {
        JLabel notationLabel = new JLabel(getAlgebraicNotation(position));
        notationLabel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 0));
        return notationLabel;
}
```

```java
public void updatePiece(char piece) {
        removeAll();

        BufferedImage pieceImage;

        if (piece == '-') {
            return;
        }

        String fileName = PIECE_ICON_PATH + piece + ".png";
        try {
            pieceImage = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: 20/3/23 Manejar excepció
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        /* Actualitza la casella */
        JLabel squareLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(pieceImage));
        squareLabel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        squareLabel.add(getAlgebraicNotationLabel(position),BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        add(squareLabel);
        validate();
}
```

The final result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> the image is not vertically centered because of the other JLabel taking part of the space

That is the way layout managers work. Components are assigned location in 2D space. So if the image is 60 X 60, then the notation label will be displayed below the image, not on top of the image.

If you want the notation label displayed on top of the image label, then you need to add the notation label to the image label.

You would need to define your image label as an instance variable in your class. In your constructor you would do something like:

```
imageLabel = new ImageLabel();
imageLabel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
add( imageLabel );

setAlgebraicNotationLabel(position);
...
```

In the `setAlgebraicNotationLabel(...)` method you would then use:

```
//add(squarePosition, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
imageLabel.add(squarePosition, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

to add the notation label to the image label, not the panel

Your `updatePiece(...)` method would then also need to be changed to use the `setIcon(...)` method to just update the `Icon` of the image label, instead of creating a new label each time.

Comment: Thanks, I did it a little different but that was a good clue!